# How long are new instances of Java stored?

Tags: java, instance

So lately I've had the question: how long is an Object stored when I create a new instance of it? Basically I'm asking how it is being stored.

Example:

```
public void initUser(Player player) {
        User u = new User(ally, player.getUuid());
        u.setHealth(20);
}
```

(User being the object)

So how long is `u` stored? Does Java clean it up after I'm done with it? (after #setHealth is called)?

Thanks.

Comment: That object is local to inituser method... as soon as it leaves the method... The object is eligible for gc...

Comment: Yes Mati, just had a look at it. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: It will be automatically garbage collected at some point after it's no longer used.

Comment: Actually since this object isn't used out side this method it might be placed on the stack using Escape Anslysis and thus be eliminated, in fact the whole method could be optimised to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special part of the **Java Runtime** called the **Garbage Collector** takes care of destroying all objects when they are no longer in use.

Application can *allocate memory* for object via explicit and implicit ways under object creation, but they *can not explicitly free that memory*.

To signal to JVM that an object is ready for garbage collection, object needs to get unrefrenced in either of below ways :

1. Explicit unreferencing
   `person = null`;  //person is an instance of Person
2. Object goes out of scope
   An Object created inside a method goes out of scope once method returns to the calling method.
   So in below case once `method()` is over, p implicitly becomes null.

   public void method(){

   Person p = new Person();
   }

After unrefrencing, VM can reclaim that memory. Virtual machine can decide when to garbage collect unrefrenced object. But specification doesn't guarantee any predictable behavior. It is up-to the VM to decide when to reclaim memory from unrefrenced object or it might NOT reclaim memory at all.

If the class declares a finalizer (i.e. `public void finalize()` method ) then Garbage Collector will execute the `finalize()` method on the instance of the class before it frees the memory space occupied by that instance.

So clearly, *exact time of garbage collection is unpredictable*.

Source: http://geekrai.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/life-cycle-of-object-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

The object which you created for User is local object. So it will be alive within the method,once the program goes out of the method this object will be eligible for GC.

```
class Test{
User u1 = new User();
public void initUser(Player player) {
    User u = new User(ally, player.getUuid());
    u.setHealth(20);
}
}
```

In the above code, the object u1 is alive through out the life of the class. If you need the object to be GC then make u1 =null

Answer (score -2):

As soon as you're done with the `Object`, Java performs gc by itself.

Comment: Thats not really true